# If $A$ is a positive linear operator on $H$ s.t. $A$'s eigenvectors form an ONB with eigenvalues $c_j$, are $\sqrt{c_j}$s eigenvalues of $\sqrt{A}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ be a positive linear operator on $H$ (not necessarily bounded). Suppose that $A$'s eigenvectors $\{e_j\}$ form an ONB for $H$ and $\{c_j\}$s are the corresponding eigenvalues of $A$. We know from spectral theory that $A$'s square root $\sqrt{A}$ exists and is positive since $A$ is positive. But is it now true that $\{\sqrt{c_j}\}$s are eigenvalues of $\sqrt{A}$?

If I recall correctly, in the cast that $A$ is bounded we have that if $\sqrt{A}$ exists, it is self-adjoint. Therefore we know that for every $e_j$, $c_j = \left<Ae_j, e_j\right> = ||\sqrt{A}e_j||^2$ whence $\sqrt{c_j}\leq ||\sqrt{A}||$. But I don't really know how to turn this approach to a proof that $\sqrt{A}e_j = \sqrt{c_j}e_j$.

Comment: In case $A$ is bounded the operator $\sqrt{A}$ can be obtained as the norm limit of operators $p_n(A),$ where $p_n$ are polynomials. If $u$ is an eigenvector of $A$ in the unbounded case, then it is an eigenvector of $\sqrt{A}.$

Answer (score 1):

How about reasoning along the following lines. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and let
$$ w = \sqrt{A}v.$$
By looking at the matrix-representation of $\sqrt{A}|_{\operatorname{span}(v,w)}$ we easily find the eigenvectors $\sqrt{\lambda}v+w$ and $\sqrt{\lambda}-w$. It is easily check that
$$\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{A}(\sqrt{\lambda}v+w) &= \sqrt{\lambda}\sqrt{A}v + Av \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda}w+\lambda v \\
&= \sqrt{\lambda}(\sqrt{\lambda}v + w)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That is a good idea! With a little refinement we get $\sqrt{A}e_j=\sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j$: Take $w = \sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j - \sqrt{A}e_j$. Then, as you suggested, $\sqrt{A}w=\sqrt{\lambda_j}\sqrt{A}e_j - Ae_j = \sqrt{\lambda_j}(\sqrt{A}e_j - \sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j) = -\sqrt{\lambda_j}w$. By assumption $\sqrt{A}\geq 0$. Now $\left<w,w\right>\geq 0$ and $\left<\sqrt{A}w,w\right>=-\sqrt{\lambda_j}||w||^2\leq 0$ . Ergo $\sqrt{\lambda_j}=0$ or $||w||=0$.

Comment: Very nice! I didnt see that refinement.

Answer (score 1):

I am including this comment as an answer and will accept it as soon as I can since it proves the claim. Inspiration for this proof is by @Testcase.

Take $w = \sqrt{c_j}e_j - \sqrt{A}e_j$. We aim to show that $||w|| = 0$. To that end,

$$\sqrt{A}w=\sqrt{c_j}\sqrt{A}e_j - Ae_j = \sqrt{c_j}(\sqrt{A}e_j - \sqrt{c_j}e_j) = -\sqrt{c_j}w$$

We assumed that $\sqrt{A}$ is positive. Therefore by $\left<w,w\right>\geq 0$, $\left<\sqrt{A}w,w\right>=-\sqrt{c_j}||w||^2\leq 0$. But this is only possible if $\sqrt{c_j}=0$ or $||w||=0$. Thus the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$A-\lambda I=(\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{\lambda}I)(\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{\lambda}I)$$ For $\lambda>0$ the first factor is an invertible operator. Therefore $(A-\sqrt{\lambda}I)v= 0$ iff $(A-\lambda I)v=0.$

Concerning $\lambda=0$ we have $\ker A=\ker A^{1/2}$ as $\langle Av,v\rangle =\|A^{1/2}v\|^2.$

The reasoning can be applied to $A^{1/n}$ by applying the formula for $b^n-a^n.$